# How to install org.apache.commons.cli using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install `org.apache.commons.cli` so it will work with OpenJDK 8. I want to install it from Eclipse (Neon) but I can't seem to figure out the url I need to add in the `Install new software`. I was looking in the [official website](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/download_cli.cgi) and I tried both the url that are shown there but they both didn't work. How should I install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Install new software" is for adding features to Eclipse itself, not for downloading third-party libraries for your application. For that, you either use a build script (Maven, Gradle, Ivy, ...) for your project, or you download the library code and add it as "External Archive" to the Build Path of your project.

Comment: Oh I see! But I can't seem to find the `jar` file in the official website. You know where to find it?

Comment: @vesii You gave the link. Download the "Binary", i.e. `commons-cli-1.4-bin.zip` (Windows) or `commons-cli-1.4-bin.tar.gz` (Linux) file, and unpack it. The jar file is inside.